# update stored procedure not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, stored-procedures

I want to know what (if any) is wrong with the below stored procedure for updating address:
I have also given my database image to get a clear idea....

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_UpdateAddress] 
    (@OriginalEmail nvarchar(50), @FirstName varchar(50), @LastName varchar(50), 
     @Country_ID int, @AddressLine1 varchar(50), @AddressLine2 varchar(50),
     @AddressLine3 varchar(50), @Telephone varchar(50), @Email nvarchar(50), 
     @City varchar(50), @State_ID int, @PostalCode varchar(50), @Mobile varchar(50))
AS
BEGIN
   DECLARE @User_ID INT

   SELECT @User_ID = ID FROM AUser Where Email = @OriginalEmail

   UPDATE [AUserAddress] 
   SET [AUser_ID] = @User_ID, [FirstName] = @FirstName, [LastName] = @LastName, 
       [Country_ID] = @Country_ID, [AddressLine1] = @AddressLine1, 
       [AddressLine2] = @AddressLine2, [AddressLine3] = @AddressLine3, 
       [Telephone] = @Telephone, [Email] = @Email, [City] = @City, 
       [State_ID] = @State_ID, [PostalCode] = @PostalCode, [Mobile] = @Mobile 
   WHERE
       Email = @OriginalEmail
END
```

Called from C#:

```
private void UpdateAddress()
{
        try
        {

            string strSession = objGetSession.GetEmailFromSession();
            con.Open();
            SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand("usp_UpdateAddress", con);
            sqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            sqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@OriginalEmail ", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50).Value = strSession;
            sqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@FirstName", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = txtFirstName.Text;
            sqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@LastName", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = txtLastName.Text;
            sqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@AddressLine1", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = txtAddressLine1.Text;
            sqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@AddressLine2", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = txtAddressLine2.Text;
            sqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@AddressLine3", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = txtAddressLine3.Text;
            sqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@Telephone", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = txtTelephone.Text;
            sqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@Email", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50).Value = txtEmailAddress.Text;
            sqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@Country_ID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = ddlCountry.SelectedItem.Value;
            sqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@City", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = txtCity.Text;
            sqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@State_ID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = ddlState.SelectedValue.ToString();
            sqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@PostalCode", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = txtPostalCode.Text;
            sqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@Mobile", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = txtMobile.Text;

            sqlCmd.Connection = con;

            sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            con.Close();

            mpeTest.Show();
            Response.Write("<script> alert('Address Updated!') </script>");
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Response.Write("An Error Occurred" + e);
        }
    }
```

[image: db]

Is the stored procedure not executing? Debugging shows that in Update Address() it does take the new value but when execution is completed, the database is not updated...

Comment: what you are missing might be **commit** transaction

Comment: @NetStarter are you sure with that?

Comment: are the two tables related with each other? if so, how?

Comment: i was having the same problem there was a stored procedure of mine which was working when executed from database and the same was getting executed from the code but the table were not updated as like Aditya then i found that transaction was not commited

Comment: Have you try to run your SP from SQL Management Studio? If not, try first to find out the problem is in your SP or in your code.

Comment: referential integrity... AUser_ID of AUserAddress table is the foreign key referring ID (primary key) of AUser table....

Comment: I tried it in SQL mgmt studio, it says command completed successfully but nothing is updated in the database...

Comment: try adding **sqlCmd.Commit();** after your line **sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();** and try it shou,ld work

Comment: How do I commit transaction (or should I say, make the transaction commit)??

Comment: Sql......... does not contain a definition for Commit()...

Comment: Are you sure your DB scheme and stored procedure are actual? In code you are updating columns like `AUserAddress.Mobile` or `AUserAddress.Email`, but there are no such columns in the `AUserAddress` table.

Comment: Sorry its the earlier image. I do have those columns in the AUserAddress table....

Comment: i was asking you to add the line in your c# code..have you tried executing your stored procedure by removing where clause

Comment: Of course I added it to C# code only.... There's no point in trying without the where clause...

Comment: i am asking you to do so to check whether the stored procedure runs without that where clause or not?

Answer (score 2):

What if you `UPDATE` it directly by joining the tables?

```
UPDATE  a
SET     a.[auser_id] = b.ID, 
        a.[firstname] = @FirstName, 
        a.[lastname] = @LastName, 
        a.[country_id] = @Country_ID, 
        a.[addressline1] = @AddressLine1, 
        a.[addressline2] = @AddressLine2, 
        a.[addressline3] = @AddressLine3, 
        a.[telephone] = @Telephone, 
        a.[email] = @Email, 
        a.[city] = @City, 
        a.[state_id] = @State_ID, 
        a.[postalcode] = @PostalCode, 
        a.[mobile] = @Mobile 
FROM    [auseraddress] a
        INNER JOIN AUser b 
            ON  a.Email = b.Email
WHERE   b.email = @OriginalEmail
```

Comment: so I should replace my Update with yours??

Comment: yep, try it (remove declcare statement and the select statement). but i have a question, is column `auseraddress.auser_id` nullable?

Comment: then what is the purpose of the select statement in your stored procedure?

Comment: see your stored procedure above, you have three statement right. `DECLARE`, `SELECT` and `UPDATE`. what is the purpose of the `SELECT` statement?

Comment: then why are you setting the `ID` here `UPDATE [AUserAddress] 
   SET [AUser_ID] = @User_ID`?

Answer (score 0):

Your stored procedure is wrong.

According to your image the AUserAddress tables does not contain a column called *Email*.